# Why this javascript is producing different output in FF and IE?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Please see this:
http://jsbin.com/igeqa

here, i am simply using

```
alert ( tableObj.childNodes.length );
```

and in FF the output is `5` , while in IE it is `2`. Please tell me what is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firefox counts whitespace text nodes, while IE is just counting elements. So Firefox is returning [#text, THEAD, #text, TBODY, #text], while IE is returning just [THEAD, TBODY].

Comment: awesome! accepted. does that mean we should not reply on `childNodes` property

Comment: It's fine to rely on childNodes, just check for "node.nodeType == 1" (element nodes) in the code that processes the childNodes to make sure they're elements if you don't want to get text nodes, comment nodes, etc.

Comment: thanks, i will use getElementsBytagName instead of childNodes

Answer (score 1):

IE and Moz count the childNodes in a HTML document in different ways. Moz counts every empty space (possible textNodes) as a childNode, while IE counts only some of them. There are several solutions for that.